# What's the qualifier for a force that's not continuously applied?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, soft-question

Some force are applied in a moment, some force are applied continuously and forever without any break in continuity. What's the opposite of that? Is there a qualifier for that? I was thinking discrete as in discrete mathematics, but discrete relates to things and not how they relate to time in a "discrete" way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word "intermittent" might be what you are looking for.  For example, there is a setting on automobile windshield wipers called "intermittent" which turns on and off the wipers from time to time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I like ad2004's word, "intermittent," but if you need something more technical, the opposite of continuous is discontinuous, with the same root as "discontinuity".

Indeed, when you get further into the math, we have varying levels of continuity or [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness).  A $C^0$ system is continuous in the way we are used to thinking about it.  A $C^1$ system also can't have any sharp corner where the rate suddenly changes.  A $C^2$ system cannot have any sharp changes in acceleration (a rocket pack that turns on suddenly and instantly cannot be $C^2$ because that sudden turn-on causes an instant change in acceleration)

Indeed, one reason that it can be hard to find the opposite of "continuous" is that continuity gives us information about the problem.  If you don't have it, that typically doesn't tell us anything useful to solve the problem with.  Instead, it tells us all of the things we can't do to solve the problem.  So its common to try to specify what kind of discontinuity we are talking about.  That gives us a hint as to how to deal with it.